# Show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, group-isomorphism

Let $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a ring of polynomials with integer coefficients, $(x)$ be an ideal generated by $x$.

Show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x)}$  is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

My attempt:

For each polynomial $$z(x) = a_nx^n + \ ...\ +a_1x + a_0$$ 
We have
$$z(x) = x\cdot(a_nx^{n-1}+ \ ... \ +a_1)\ + a_0$$.
Hence if we define $\Phi : \mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x)} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ as:

$$\Phi(a_nx^n +\ ... \ +a_1x + a_0 +(x)) =\Phi((a_nx^{n-1} +\ ... \ +a_1)x + a_0 +(x)) = \Phi(a_0 + (x)) = a_0$$.

My first question is about notation and equivalence class. How do I write that two polynomials $w(x), z(x)$ are equivalent if their $a_0, b_0$ coefficients are equal?

I will try to show that such $\Phi$ is homomorphism.
For two polynomials $z(x), w(x)$ with coefficients $a_i, b_i$ respectively we have:

$\Phi((z+(x)) + (w+(x))) = \Phi((z+w)+(x)) = \Phi((a_0+b_0)+(x)) = a_0 + b_0 = \Phi(z+(x)) + \Phi(w+(x))$.

And from now I have trouble to show that there is unique element in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x)}$ that corresponds to an element of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Can it be fixed? My main concern is how to properly write the equivalence relation and how do I proceed with my proof further. Would be grateful for any hints.

**Edit:**

I will try the other way around.
Define $$\psi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x)}$$ as follows

$$\psi(a) = a + (x)$$

Showing that $\psi$ is homomorphism

$$\psi(a) + \psi(b) = (a+(x)) + (b+(x)) = (a+b) + (x) = \psi(a+b)$$

Suppose that $\psi(a) = \psi(b)$

We have

$$a + (x) = b + (x)$$

Which leads to $(a-b) \in (x)$ how do I conclude that $a-b = 0$? Since I am missing something.

Moreover, I am struggling with showing that for every element in quotient space there is some number in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Comment on your attempt:

You may find it easier (see "**alternate method**" below) to try to define the homomorphism the other way around -- from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x)$. The problem is that the way you are doing, it is kind of confusing to work with $\Phi$ because it really is a function on equivalence classes. It can be done, but requires that you show $\Phi$ is first well-defined. Normally you would do this the following way:

- First define $\Phi$ on a particular element, *not* on equivalence classes (i.e. define $\Phi(a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n) := a_0$)
- Next show this is a well-defined operation *on equivalence classes* -- to do this you should consider two equivalent polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x)$, and show that $\Phi$ is the same on those two polynomials.

Once you have that $\Phi$ is well defined, the rest of the proof is easier: any time you want to evaluate $\Phi$, it is enough to evaluate it on some member of the equivalence class, so you don't have to worry about having "$+ (x)$" everywhere in your proof.

#### Alternate method

Alternatively instead of $\Phi$ you can try defining

$$
\psi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} [x] / (x).
$$

Then you don't have to show $\psi$ is well-defined. Instead, you just have to show that

- It is a homomorphism
- It is one-to-one: this amounts to showing that if $\psi(a)$ and $\psi(b)$ *are equivalent* (differ by something in $(x)$), then $a = b$.
- It is onto: this amounts to fixing some polynomial $a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$, and showing *it is equivalent* to something that $\psi$ produces as output.

Comment: Thank you I will try your method. But the question is how do I find a form of $\psi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x)}$? I mean does it have an exact form?

Comment: @janusz Basically, you just define $\psi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[x]$; you don't need to worry about the $/ (x)$ until you are talking about the one-to-one and onto parts. This is because the "up to equivalence mod $x$" doesn't matter for defining the function

Comment: To be honest I don't how to proceed right know. Is there an exact form of such $\psi$? Without it I'm not able to operate.

Comment: I was thinking about defining $\psi(a) := a + (x)$, showing that this is indeed homomorphism is fine, showing that this is injective I think wouldn't be a problem since only consant element of $(x)$ is $0$, so it will result in $a=b$. But what about being surjective?

Comment: @janusz It is clearer to think of polynomials "up to equivalence mod $x$" rather than equivalence classes like $a + (x)$. That avoids dealing with set arithmetic everywhere like $(x) + (x)$. So I would just define $\psi(a) := a$. To show surjectiveness, you need to show that for any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, there is an equivalent polynomial that $\psi$ maps to.