# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-isomorphism

Showing that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, where $(x)$ is an ideal generated by $x$.

**My attempt:**

I will try to show that $\psi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x)}$ defined below is indeed isomorphism:

$$\psi(a) := a + (x)$$

1) Being homomorphism

$$\psi(a) + \psi(b) = (a + (x)) + (b+(x)) = (a+b) + (x) = \psi(a+b)$$

2) Being injecitve

Suppose that $\psi(a) = \psi(b) \Rightarrow (a-b) \in (x)$, but the only constant in $(x)$ is $0$ hence $a=b$

Is it correct  up to this point?

3) Being surjective

I have trouble with this point.

Any hints would be great.

Also I am posting possible duplicate, a post of mine but with different approach:
[Different method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673169/show-that-mathbbzx-x-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbz/3673185?noredirect=1#comment7548388_3673185)

Comment: Perhaps try and define a homomorphism in the other direction which is surjective, then show that the kernel is $(x)$ and use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Hint: Dividing $P(x)$ by $x$ using Euclidean division, we get $P(x)=xQ(x)+R(x)$, where $\deg(R)<\deg(x)$.

Comment: @Karl $\mathbb Z[x]$ is not a Euclidean domain, but it's true that it works in this case.

Comment: Show that the map $\psi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined as $\psi (p(x)) = p(0)$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with $\ker \psi = (x)$. The result follows from the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Yes, this idea with first theorem works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine up to this point. To prove it is surjective, let
$$p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$
Then this is equal to
$$a_0+x\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{i-1}$$
But $x\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{i-1}\in (x)$. Since this polynomial was arbitrary, all polynomials are of the form $a+xf(x)$ for some polynomial $f(x)$, hence all elements in $\mathbb Z[x]/(x)$ are of the form $a+(x)$ for $a\in\mathbb Z$.